# jQuery Transitions?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation, transition

I want to use jquery to access a hover state on a li element. Before hovering on it, it is gray. When you hover on it, it becomes red and underlined. You could do this in css, but the trick is that I want it to transition from the left of the li to the right so it appears to be sliding color in.

Comment: [What Have You Tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: Do you have some code for what you've tried so far? I'd be happy to take a look.

Comment: li {
 display: inline;
 color:#999;
 padding:5px;
}
li:hover{
color:#df2724;
text-decoration:underline;
}

Comment: I could do transition:all 1s linear;, but I want the transition to happen from left to right in jQuery, and I dont have enough knowledge to do it yet :/ im thinking changing the hover state to a class, and just adding the class in jquery on hover, and then animating the transition

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking about animating the underlining of the li:

Create a thin (2px tall, width of the li) red div that contains a thin (same size) white div inside of it.  You should only be able to see the white, covering the red div completely.

Make sure the red div has overflow:hidden as a css property.  Then do a jQuery animate to move the white div to the right, creating the illusion of a red line slowly underlining the li.  When someone mouses over any li, find the closest "red/white" nested divs and perform the animate on the white div.  Kinda like this:

```
$("li").hover(function(){
    $(this).next('div').children('div').animate({left: (width of div)px});
});
```

The next('div') finds the red div, then the children('div') finds the white div inside of it.  The animate function moves the white div out of the way, exposing the red div.

Comment: I just noticed you were speaking about the li itself having the animation, as opposed to the underline.  Same concept, but you'll have to use nested divs (of different colors, overlapping) as backgrounds inside the li to accomplish the desired effect.

Comment: Is there anyway to just animate the hover state from left to right? sorry, im not familiar with javascript/jquery.

Comment: Unfortunately, the only way to accomplish that animation is with these nested divs and the animate() function, or some similar idea.

The most difficult part about it is understanding the DOM and traversing it with next(), parent(), and children().

Good luck in your endeavors.

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried this example:

http://www.incg.nl/blog/2008/hover-block-jquery/

Or this with lavalamp plugin:
http://www.gmarwaha.com/blog/2007/08/23/lavalamp-for-jquery-lovers/

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH! the lava lamp thing was just what I was looking for! I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

It is better to have a background image which of the required color in the li dimension. So that you can make an animation effect when the mouseover and mouseout events the li. On mouse over animate the background image from background-position of some '-' to 0 and on mouse out do the reverse.